# React only .map certain elements of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have an array which stores 3 various keys, for example, in this format dependant of the entry. It is called finalselected and will be an array of selections made.

```
https://gyazo.com/c8d180c381fb07b950ae9605e6e6ed03
```

Dependant on the selections, it comes through in elements like this:

```
{
    "education": "Master's Degree"
}
{
    "experience": "A similar role",
    "inputfield": "3"
}
```

However, I want a component to map ONLY over the "experience" and "input" fields, as it's going to display for example {experience} for {inputField} years.

I have assembled a mapped component however it is currently coming through with a mapped component when education exists. How would you re-write this to only map over these 2 keys?

```
{finalselected.map((perkTitle) => (
  <SelectionBoxesChoiceOptionQual  >

  <Typography 
      variant="h5" fontSize="25px"  
      style={ {color: 'white'}}
      >
          {perkTitle.inputfield}
  </Typography>
      
      <Typography 
          variant="h5" fontSize="6px"  
          style={ {color: 'white'}}
          >
              years in
      </Typography>

      <Typography 
          variant="h5" fontSize="8px"  
          style={ {color: 'white'}}
          >
              {perkTitle.experience}
      </Typography>

  </SelectionBoxesChoiceOptionQual>
))}
```

As said above, I only wanted to map for specifically elements with these two "experience" & "inputField". How would I do this?

Comment: Filter _then_ map?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter ?

Answer (score 1):

// filter the array with experience and inputfield and map the values

```
const filteredArray = array.filter((item) => item.experience).map((item) => item.experience);
```